# Did India give a reason why it objected to China joining the Hague Apostille Convention?

Tags: china, india

> On March 8, 2022, China officially acceded to the Convention
> Abolishing the Requirement of Legalisation for Foreign Public
> Documents, also known as the “Hague Apostille Convention.” The
> Apostille Convention will officially go into effect in China on
> November 7, 2023.
>
> The Convention was adopted by the Hague Conference on Private
> International Law (HCCH) in 1961, and it has since been ratified by
> over 120 countries and territories worldwide, including Hong Kong and
> Macao, the United States, the Philippines, United Kingdom, and
> Australia.
>
> For a complete list of countries and territories that are party to the
> Convention, see the HCCH | #12 – Status table.
>
> For countries that are not party to the Apostille Convention, the
> current authentication process will remain in place. This includes
> Canada (for which the Convention will enter into force on Jan. 11,
> 2024), Rwanda (for which the Convention will enter into force on June
> 5, 2024), Thailand, and Vietnam.
>
> Note that India has objected to China joining the Convention, so
> apostilles issued in India cannot be used in China, and vice-versa.

https://lawandborder.com/china-joins-hague-apostille-convention/

Did India give a reason why it objected to China joining the Hague Apostille Convention? The Hague Apostille Convention, also known as the Apostille Treaty or the Apostille Convention, is an international treaty that simplifies the process of authenticating documents for use in foreign countries. The convention was established to eliminate the need for lengthy and complicated authentication procedures, making the international legalization of documents more efficient. Now, India objected to China joining. My question is whether there's a public statement made by India explaining why they objected.

Comment: I'm guessing because they don't yet want to accept Chinese-issued documents without authentication. Makes sense given the geopolitical situation and populations. There has been no public statement by MEA or any of the embassies.